# Jquery collect atributtes to mount (numbers)

Tags: jquery

I have a list (ul list) and every li item has a 'data-pret' . I want to collect from li who has the class '.selectat' and put in text, like a mount.

Ex: 10 + 20 + 15 = 45

http://jsfiddle.net/wdLaR/

HTML:

```
     <div class="div">
          <ul class="lista-analize">
                    <li class="a" data-pret="10">Hemoleucogramă completă <span class="pret">10 lei</span></li>
                    <li class="a" data-pret="15">Numărare reticulocite <span class="pret">15 lei</span></li>
                    <li class="a" data-pret="20">VSH <span class="pret">20 lei</span></li>
                    <li class="a" data-pret="10">INR (International Normalised Ratio) <span class="pret">10 lei</span></li>
                    <li class="a" data-pret="15">Determinare grup sanguin ABO <span class="pret">15 lei</span></li>
                    <li class="a" data-pret="25">Determinare grup sanguin RH <span class="pret">25 lei</span></li>
                    <li class="a" data-pret="35">Colinesteraza <span class="pret">35 lei</span></li>
                    <li class="a" data-pret="5">Proteine serice totale <span class="pret">5 lei</span></li>
                    <li class="a" data-pret="15">Hemoglobina glicozilată (HbA1C) <span class="pret">15 lei</span></li>
                    <li class="a" data-pret="20">Factor rheumatoid <span class="pret">20 lei</span></li>
                </ul>

                <span id="total"></span>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.content-stanga').on('click', 'li.a', function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("selectat", 200);

   var sume = 0;

while (($(this).hasClass("selectat")) && (sume === 0)) { 
  var sume = +$(this).data("pret");
}

$('#total').text(sume);

});
});
```

Comment: `= +`?  Should not it be `+=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each()` to sum the data values where the element has that class. Also, you do not want to use the `var` keyword when setting the value of `sume` within the loop, and the condition to check if `sume == 0` is counter-productive with getting the total of the selected elements, as it will only add the first item. Finally, to increment a variable with a value, it's `+=`, not `= +`.

Try this:

```
$('.content-stanga').on('click', 'li.a', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("selectat");
    var sume = 0;
    $('.content-stanga li.a.selectat').each(function() {
        sume += $(this).data('pret');
    });
    $('#total').text(sume);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xv96X/1/)

Comment: Oh thanks for that, it work very good. But you cand explain me about (e) after function, e.preventeDefault(); ? I`m work with basics..